# firebase dynamic link shared on twitter is not working at webbrower

Tags: android, firebase, twitter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using firebase dynamic link to share contents in my android app.

It works fine if i click the link shared to twitter by using twitter app.
The link launch my android app and bring me to the right page on app.

But if i click the link from webbrowser, my app never be launched. 
It just bring me to the fallback page where the webpage specified in afl parameter.

And there is some other cases.
If i open the link at new tab or secret tab, It works fine.

Please give some helps!
Thanks!

============== updated ===========

I had some test and the results are below.
It looks like depending on browser.

Chrome

1. click directly : not working
2. open new tab or secret tab : works

Firefox

1. click directly : works
2. open new tab : works

Penguin

1. click directly : not working
2. open new tab : not working

opera

1. click directly : works
2. open new tab : works

Star Safari

1. click directly : works
2. open new tab : works

Comment: Which android web browser failed to open the app? Did the browser do anything else?

Comment: @albertbraun I added some test results. It looks like depending browser and opening way the link.

Answer (score 1):

Typing a link in directly to Safari will always open it in Safari. Apple figure that a user that does that has intentionally requested the web page. Tapping a link in a page however, should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know some browsers (e.g. chrome) needs the user to intentionally click on the link to open the app, so my question is: is the link triggered by any script? If so chrome won't work
As I've just seen chrome is one of the browsers that doesn't work fine so I think that has to do with their script to recognise if the link was triggered by the user or not. If you want to you could use [android intents](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) to open it from chrome but, obviously, you won't have any analytics script pre-built.